# Avoiding instance of to filter by type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, algebraic-data-types, typesafe

I currently have the following (not type safe) api which I'm trying to redesign in a typesafe way:

```
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.functorFilter._


sealed trait EnumType
case object A extends EnumType
case object B extends EnumType
case object C extends EnumType

sealed abstract class TypeInfo[T <: EnumType](val enumType: T)
case class Ainfo() extends TypeInfo(A)
case class Ainfo2() extends TypeInfo(A)
case class Binfo() extends TypeInfo(B)
case class Cinfo() extends TypeInfo(C)

//This is the function implemented in a not typesafe way
def filterByEnumType[T <: EnumType: ClassTag](lst: List[TypeInfo[_]]): List[TypeInfo[T]] = {
  lst mapFilter { info =>
    info.enumType match {
      case _: T => Some(info.asInstanceOf[TypeInfo[T]]) //not type safe
      case _    => None
    }
  }
}

filterByEnumType[A.type](List(Ainfo(), Binfo(), Ainfo2(), Cinfo()))  //List(Ainfo(), Ainfo2())
```

Is there an approach to implement it typesafely? Are typemembers useful for such task or probbably `shapeless` can be used for that?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with two related approaches with shapeless. I'm not sure either will exactly meet your needs because they depend on having all the types of the elements of the list known ahead of time.

Assuming you have this stuff:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

type HType = TypeInfo[A.type] :: TypeInfo[B.type] :: TypeInfo[A.type] :: TypeInfo[C.type] :: HNil
val hlist: HType = Ainfo() :: Binfo() :: Ainfo2() :: Cinfo() :: HNil
```

You can use filter on the `HList` directly:

```
hlist.filter[TypeInfo[A.type]] // Ainfo() :: Ainfo2() :: HNil
```

If you want to avoid explicitly specifying `TypeInfo` in the filter call you can modify your filter function (but now you're required to give the HList type -- this can be worked around using a proxy class):

```
def filterByEnumType[T <: EnumType, L <: HList](
    list: L
)(implicit filter: Filter[L, TypeInfo[T]]): filter.Out = {
  filter.apply(list)
}

filterByEnumType[A.type, HType](hlist) // Ainfo() :: Ainfo2() :: HNil
```

Comment: Looks good for the use-case, but in case of unknown types I think the `asInstanceOf` is not that bad as it might seem at first...

Comment: @SomeName correct, the shapeless version won't work if the type are unknown. That's fairly typical of any shapeless solution.